# Javascript Object Map (flatten)

Tags: javascript, object, dictionary, flatten

Hello I have an object that outputs to this using JSON.Stringify

```
{"0":["test1","ttttt","","","","","","","",""],"1":["test2","ghjgjhgjh","","","","","","","",""]}
```

**I would like to have the output like this.**

```
[["test1","ttttt","","","","","","","",""],["test2","ghjgjhgjh","","","","","","","",""]]
```

I have tried this to remove "0" and "1" by using .map

```
var itemjson = $.map(cleanedGridData, function (n) {
        return n;
    });
```

however this gives an output of (below) which has flattened to far.

```
["test1", "ttttt", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "test2", "ghjgjhgjh", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your return statement to put `n` in another array.

```
return [n];
```

This is because jQuery's `$.map` flattens the array you return into the result, so you need to wrap it in an outer array.

Either that, or just use a `for in` loop.

```
var itemjson = [];
for (var key in cleanedGridData) {
  itemjson.push(cleanedGridData[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to pull out the values:

```
var res = {"0":["test1","ttttt","","","","","","","",""],"1":["test2","ghjgjhgjh","","","","","","","",""]}
Object.keys(res).map(function(key) {
    return res[key];
});
```

Object.keys will list all of the keys in your initial object.  You can then iterate through those keys using map and pull the values out in that function.

Comment: I do like solutions that don't require jquery :)

Answer (score 0):

Once your environment (i.e. in case of browsers all browsers you want to support) has [`Object.values`](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/#test-Object_static_methods_Object.values) (and [spread operator](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-spread_(...)_operator_with_arrays,_in_array_literals)) available you can go for

```
[...Object.values(cleanedGridData)]
```